# How to run 2 times of do-while loop only?

Tags: java, loops, do-while

How to modify the code below to become the user only can enter 2 times wrong PIN? After 2 times wrong PIN, the program will auto exit.

```
    String user = "Melissa";
    int pin = 123456;
    int pin2;

    // Prompt the user for input
    do
    {
        String pin2String = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter PIN");
        pin2 = Integer.parseInt(pin2String);
    }while(pin2 != pin);

    // Display
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "User: "+ user);
```

Comment: Uh.  How about adding a counter so at the start of the `do{` loop it has something like `if (++counter > 2) { get angry... }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will just need to add a counter, to count how many times the user has attempted to enter a pin, then verify the condition in your `while` loop's condition.

For example:

```
 String user = "Melissa";
 int pin = 123456;
 int pin2;
 int MAX_INCORRECT_PIN_THRESHOLD = 2;
 int attempts = 0;

 // Prompt the user for input
 do {
     String pin2String = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter PIN");
     pin2 = Integer.parseInt(pin2String);
     attempts++;
 } while(pin2 != pin && attempts < MAX_INCORRECT_PIN_THRESHOLD);

 if (pin2 == pin) {
     // Display
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "User: "+ user);
 }
```

Comment: if MAX_INCORRECT_PIN_THRESHOLD = 2; attempts = 0; the total wrong time can be 3

Comment: Sorry, that should be `attempts < MAX_INCORRECT_PIN_THRESHOLD`, not `attempts <= MAX_INCORRECT_PIN_THRESHOLD`.  I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Alright, appreciate your helping since i'm a beginner in programming~ Thanks a lot~

Answer (score 0):

```
int counter = 0;
 do
    { if(counter++ >= 2){ break;}
        String pin2String = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter PIN");
        pin2 = Integer.parseInt(pin2String);
    }while(pin2 != pin);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a for loop where it only loops twice. That would probably be easier.

```
VALID:
for(int i= 0; i < 2; i++){
  if(pin==pin2){
    //Valid login...
    break VALID;
  }else if(i == 1){
   System.exit(0);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Drop a simple counter in there which terminates the loop after two iterations, and then check to see if the PIN was invalid after leaving the loop:

```
String user = "Melissa";
int pin = 123456;
int pin2;
int count = 0;

// Prompt the user for input
do
{
    String pin2String = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter PIN");
    pin2 = Integer.parseInt(pin2String);
}while(pin2 != pin && count++ < 2);

if(pin2 != pin)
{
  // Kansas is going bye-bye - call exit logic
}

// Display
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "User: "+ user);
```